# Google DoubleClick - Do Floating adverts require a visible Close button on Mobile Browsers?

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, double-click-advertising

I'm currently trying to become certified to create DoubleClick adverts, and I'm following Google's own [certification program video](https://getstudiocert.appspot.com/studiocert/static/wvplayer/index.html?title=StudioCertCoreHTML5&utm_source=learncenter&utm_medium=en&utm_campaign=html5Video), and it seems to contradict itself.

It states that close buttons are required for floating (interstitial) adverts, but halfway through their video the following happens:

[image]

Visible Close Buttons are NOT required for Mobile Browsers!

There is no further explanation as to why a Mobile Browser doesn't require a visible close button, and elsewhere in the video, and Google's documentation, it simply states visible close buttons ARE required:

[image]

In [their documentation](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/165130?hl=en), it is also clearly stated:

[image]

This is stated again [elsewhere in their documentation](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2853136?hl=en-GB), this time clearly including "mobile browser":

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming as outlined in the faq.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for opening dialogue. I would argue this is a question about what code is required in certain situations when coding an ad. It falls under the FAQ as "software commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they meant "In-App" interstitial adverts when they said "Mobile Browser". You don't need to include code for a Close Button if you're building an interstitial for in-app use.